# helm/kubernetes not installing all cronjobs in list

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart which involves a loop over a range of values. The chart includes a statefulset, pvc and cronjob. If I pass it a list with 4 values, all is well, but if I pass it a list of 12 values, most of the cronjobs just don't appear in the final template (i.e. using `helm install --dry-run --debug`).

Can anyone explain what might be causing this? I googled to see if I could find information about maximum length of templates but couldn't find anything...

`helm template` creates the manifest just fine, so maybe it's kubernetes is rejecting the cronjobs for some reason?

Is there a recommended approach for when you need to create many almost-duplicates of a manifest?

EXAMPLE: The chart template looks something like this

```
{{ $env := .Release.Namespace }}
{{ $image_tag := .Values.image_tag }}
{{ $aws_account_id := .Values.aws_account_id }}
{{- range $collector := .Values.collectors }}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ $colname }}
  labels:
    app: {{ $colname }}
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: {{ $colname }}
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ $colname }}
  labels:
    app: {{ $colname }}
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: {{ $colname }}
  serviceName: {{ $colname }}
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ $colname }}
    spec:
      securityContext:
          fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: {{ $colname }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: {{ $aws_account_id }}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/d:{{ $image_tag }}
        volumeMounts:
        - name: {{ $colname  }}-a-claim
          mountPath: /home/me/a
        - name: {{ $colname  }}-b-claim
          mountPath: /home/me/b
        - name: {{ $colname  }}-c-claim
          mountPath: /home/me/c
        env:
        - name: COLLECTOR
          value: {{ $collector }}
        - name: ENV
          value: {{ $env }}
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: {{ $colname  }}-a-claim
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: gp2
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi
  - metadata:
      name: {{ $colname }}-b-claim
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: gp2
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
  - metadata:
      name: {{ $colname }}-c-claim
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: gp2
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ $colname }}-c-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gp2
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi

---

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ $colname }}-cron
spec:
  schedule: {{ $update_time }}
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1000
          containers:
          - name: {{ $colname }}
            image: {{ $aws_account_id }}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/d:{{ $image_tag }}
            env: 
            - name: COLLECTOR
              value: {{ $collector_name }}
            volumeMounts:
            - name: c-storage
              mountPath: /home/me/c
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - name: c-storage
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: {{ $colname }}-c-claim

--- 

{{ end }}
```

and I'm passing values like:

```
collectors: 
        - name: a
        - name: b
        - name: c
        - name: d 
        - name: e 
        - name: f 
        - name: g 
        - name: h 
        - name: i 
        - name: j
        - name: k 
        - name: l
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you are trying to do? What helm version your are using?

Comment: @thomas it's helm 3 and I've added an example now. Weird thing is that I can't reproduce the error now.. so maybe something to do with the state of the cluster?